Inserting information into 2 tables when a user signs up with Identity
I'm creating a web app that has 2 components the public-facing site where companies can get information and sign up for the service and users can log in, and a web portal where logged in users are directed to. I want to use the Entity Identity Framework for handling logging in, signing up and user roles. when a company signs up from the public facing site I want the company added to a Companies table and also create a ADMIN user role associated with the provided email and password. Other users will be created from the web portal by those with the required role.
My first question, is this even possible using Identity? If so how do I go about creating the relationship between the Company and AccountUsers table?

Looks like you have a Frontend which is a HTTP connection from clients to a server for both public-facing and web portal.  The type of data can be different depending on the route.  Then you have a backend for the public facing site which is a connection to a database.  You'll have multiple routes where each route access can be limited to a Group, User, or Role.  Entity will be used in the backend connection.  The client will need to serialize the data for the database and then the controller will deserialize the data for the database and then transfer data to database using Entity.
